# How to keep static resource in memory in python web app?

Tags: python, image, web-applications, resources

I implemented a python web app, which generates images dynamically using small pieces of images.
Each time when user visit the page, a script runs and all small images are loaded from disc to generate big image. 
I think loading small images from disc is quite a big overhead. Is it possible to load all small images once, and all other python scripts can use it freely whenever called?

Answer (score 2):

The images will be most likely cached by the system virtual memory unless you are running out of memory.
In any case, it's common practice to always run webapps behind a fast webserver and let the webserver serve static images.
The webapp could simply send the img tags to the browser, than the browser would load them from the webserver

Comment: I am afraid you misunderstood my question. I need to run a script which read image files from disc many times, and I wish to have the image cached in memory so that the script (rather than server) don't need to always read files.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way is not having your Python program quit at all. One way to accomplish this is with FastCGI: http://docs.python.org/howto/webservers.html#fastcgi-and-scgi

Comment: Or `mod_wsgi` in Daemon mode.